# Best way to generate complex dynamic elements based on selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form with a dropdown which is for selecting parentCategory:(car, car parts, bike, MC, autobuss, etc).

Each category may have a subcategory or subviews(textbox, checkbox, dropdowns etc) or both.

Each subcategory may also have subviews(textbox checkbox dropdowns etc)

example:

```
 if user selects "car" 
    {
    generate 4 different dropdowns(year model[get options from db], milage[get options from db], bensin or disel, manual/automatic)
     generate 1 textField(registration number)
    }

 if user selects "car parts"
    {
    generate a subcategory dropdown with items(gps, car parts, tire, car stereo)
    //if subcategory.value changes then look if there is subView. 
    ex: if subcategory.value is "car part", then generate 1 dropdown(whichCarSection)
    }
 if user selects "bike"
    {
    generate a subcategory dropdown with items from database
    }
```

What is simplest way to achieve this request? 
I have been able to generet a dropdown if parentcategory has subCategory. (in my example: when user selects "tire")

How can I generete the subViews?
Where do I store the subView elements?

What I have done so long is this: 
I have a table in mysql with category items.

```
catID - catTitle  - hasSubCat 
100     - car       - 0        
120     - car parts - 1 
130     - bikes     - 1
```

I have a table in mysql for subCategory items.

```
subCatId - subCatTitle - parentCat 
0        - gps         - 120         
1        - car part    - 120        
2        - tire        - 120
3        - BMX         - 130
4        - BMW         - 130
5        - Mountain    - 130
```

Comment: You'll need javascript or jquery to do that I think.

Comment: I know, that is not a problem. my question is where&how do I store the subViews.

Comment: I think you place the submenus in hidden `<div>`s and then call the jquery .show() method on them. But if you want the dropdowns to be populated with items from the database, you'll need ajax too.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to see you modeling the data ahead from modeling the UI. First I would like to see you review MVC in PHP (http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html)- then decide the M from your MVC (by the way Ruby on Rails does this automatically by having its M reflect the tables directly). 
Next step is to decide on a view. This application could mechanise everything at the client with the PHP generating Javascript lists to represent the M at the client - it requires that all the data be downloaded. It could also sent code to attach events to the UI for to exchange or generated the V of your application at the client - this could be a set of tabs for the main category and tabs with subcategory dropdowns or radio buttons for the content of your tabs, etc. 
The alternative when data gets much larger is to introduce AJAX to the client server interaction. This complicates the client and the server but make it more responsive when data volume is higher. Again M at the server would update itself on orders by the C (controller) on response to events or input generated by V (the view at the client).
I hope this helps, as I think that providing any code is not the best for your case.